# Why does my Linux mint freeze?

Tags: linux-mint, mate-desktop

I am running Linux mint 32 bit. My problem is that the operating system freezes randomly. When this happens, the only solution I have is to shut down by pushing the power button of my laptop, because neither my laptop keys nor mouse nor touch pad works or responds. I have encountered this problem with both the 64 bit and the 32 bit versions.

Some relevant information:

```
sai@SRKheaven ~ $ inxi -Fxz
System:    Host: SRKheaven Kernel: 3.2.0-23-generic i686 (32 bit, gcc: 4.6.3) Desktop: Gnome Distro: Linux Mint 13 Maya
Machine:   System: Acer (portable) product: Aspire V3-571 version: V1.07
           Mobo: Acer model: VA50_HC_CR version: Type2 - Board Version Bios: Acer version: V1.07 date: 05/11/2012
CPU:       Dual core Intel Core i5-3210M CPU (-HT-MCP-) cache: 3072 KB flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 9977.76 
           Clock Speeds: 1: 1200.00 MHz 2: 1200.00 MHz 3: 1200.00 MHz 4: 1200.00 MHz
Graphics:  Card: Intel Ivy Bridge Graphics Controller bus-ID: 00:02.0 
           X.Org: 1.11.3 drivers: intel (unloaded: fbdev,vesa) Resolution: 1366x768@60.0hz 
           GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Ivybridge Mobile x86/MMX/SSE2 GLX Version: 2.1 Mesa 8.0.4 Direct Rendering: Yes
Audio:     Card: Intel Panther Point High Definition Audio Controller driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1b.0
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture ver: 1.0.24
Network:   Card-1: Broadcom BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n driver: wl bus-ID: 03:00.0
           IF: eth1 state: up mac: <filter>
           Card-2: Broadcom NetLink BCM57785 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe driver: tg3 ver: 3.121 bus-ID: 02:00.0
           IF: eth0 state: down mac: <filter>
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 500.1GB (1.7% used) 1: /dev/sda TOSHIBA_MK5059GS 500.1GB 
Partition: ID: / size: 97G used: 8.0G (9%) fs: ext4 ID: swap-1 size: 4.12GB used: 0.00GB (0%) fs: swap 
Sensors:   Error: You do not have the sensors app installed.
Info:      Processes: 171 Uptime: 37 min Memory: 948.2/2622.6MB Runlevel: 2 Gcc sys: 4.6.3 Client: Shell inxi: 1.7.33
```

How can I resolve this freezing? What could be the exact problem for this type of behavior? Is it the only solution to shut down box manually?

---

**Update:**

1. Are you using the native drivers for the Nvidia graphics card or the ones included with your distro?

   - No, I did not install any drivers explicitly.
2. Are you doing anything specific when the freezing occurs?

   - Specifically, I have opened Google Chrome. At one instance it froze. None of the shortcut works, neither ctrl+alt+F1 or any other.
   - Some other time, I have opened Firefox and it froze.
   - Another time, when I was typing something in the gedit text editor.
3. What applications are running when the freezing occurs?

   - Browser, like Chrome. Firefox, Gedit are opened. And these are opened at different times.

Comment: According to [this](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=61&t=121383) Mint (13 and 14) has had some freezing issues on various models of laptop recently. The people in that thread are saying the solution to their problem was to upgrade to 3.7.4

Comment: Also, make sure it is a full freeze. What happens if you hit Ctrl+Alt+F1? What about Ctrl+Alt+Backspace or Ctrl+Alt+Del? If the computer responds to these shortcuts, your problem is only at the graphical interface level.

Answer (score 3):

Though your question is simply put what you ask is going to be difficult to diagnose. There are a multitude of reasons why a computer and the software on it can present as unstable or having periodic freezes.

Think of this analogy:

> If you went to a doctor and asked them why you got a cold, they
>   couldn't just plainly answer it. They'd have to do an exhaustive
>   histology to determine potential situations where you may have picked
>   up the virus.

The same goes with diagnosing an unstable computer. We'll have to develop a histology of sorts by getting specific information from you about the following:

- Make of hardware
- What version of Linux Distro you're using
- Establish a pattern of use that may lead to the freezing
- Software setup and configurations
- Any special peripherals
- 3rd party drivers

This list goes on. You've made a first good step in providing the info from the `inxi` command but we'll need a bit more. For starters:

1. Are you using the native drivers for the Nvidia graphics card or the ones included with your distro?
2. Are you doing anything specific when the freezing occurs?
3. What applications are running when the freezing occurs?

My typical approach is to turn everything off that you don't need and see if the problem persists. If it does then dig deeper. If it goes away then slowly introduce the software turned off prior one at a time and try and isolate the one particular piece that's causing the issue.

Comment: I remember, this freezing happened for me twice, when I have opened chrome.

Comment: @srk - if I were you I'd start with running the laptop through something like [memtest86](http://www.memtest86.com/download.htm). This will show whether there is something up with your hardware.

Comment: Please see my update.

Comment: @srk - OK please see my prior comment and try and run the application `memtest86`. You need to try and eliminate a hardware issue before proceeding any further with exploring software issues. `memtest86` will need to be burned to a CD/DVD/USB thumbdrive and your system will boot from this media. This run should be allowed for 24 hours to exercise the system for potential hardware problems.